# Send emails from external mail server in Magento 1.9

Tags: email, magento

I'm trying to get Magento to send transactional emails via our external mail server. I've tried using the SMTP Pro extention, but that didn't work.

I've changed the getMail function in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php to:

```
public function getMail()
{
if (is_null($this->_mail)) {
$my_smtp_host = 'xxx';
$my_smtp_port = '587';
$config = array(
'port' => $my_smtp_port, 'auth' => 'login',
'username' => 'xxx',
'password' => 'xxx' );
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host, $config);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
$this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
}
return $this->_mail;
}
```

but the emails are still sending from the local server.

(I know editing core files is bad, this is solely for testing purposes.)

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you may achieve that by setting up a relay between magento server and external mail server. no code changes are necessary if it is an option.